# Macro to fill out cells based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

So I am faced with a problem while trying to setup a macro in excel. I have an existing excel with a lot of data present in the following format.

```
Ent Name Change Status
----------------------
01  AAA  ok
02  AAA [blank]
03  AAA ok
01  BBB ok
02  BBB ok
03  BBB ok
01  CCC [blank]
02  CCC ok
01  DDD ok
02  DDD ok
03  DDD ok
04  DDD ok
```

Now the task is there is a fourth column to this data set. I am to populate that with 'Done' if for all instances of a value in the second column, the corresponding third column says 'ok'. But if that's not the case then the fourth column remains empty. So in this case the output will be

```
Ent Name Change Status
----------------------
01  AAA  ok
02  AAA [blank]
03  AAA ok
01  BBB ok      Done
02  BBB ok      Done
03  BBB ok      Done
01  CCC [blank]
02  CCC ok
01  DDD ok      Done
02  DDD ok      Done
03  DDD ok      Done
04  DDD ok      Done
```

So in the above example values BBB and DDD are getting the 'Done' in the Status column, since for all their entries there is a 'Ok' in the Change column. If AAA or CCC didn't have a blank in their corresponding Change column, they would have had 'done' in their fourth column too.
I understand that using a macro to filter out would do half the job. But the part where I am stuck is how to loop through the instances of a particular value in Name, to check the corresponding change column value. Any pointers?

Comment: Does it have to be vba? Sounds like you could do this with formulas, e.g. with `IF` and `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Has to be vba unfortunately. I offered a solution using COUNTIFS, but they need a one button solution to it, which can be applied to multiple excels if required, rather than recreating the formula for all of the worksheets.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the condition is that causes you to mark `Done` in the fourth column

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 The condition is that for all instances of a specific value in the second column, if the corresponding value is 'ok', the the fourth column will get 'Done' in them. For example, in the above example I have mentioned, for all of the 'BBB' values in the second column, the third column shows 'ok', whereas for AAA there is one row which is [blank]. Therefore all rows with 'BBB' gets 'Done', but the other rows do not.

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it, for each grouping in `Name`, if all of the adjacent cells in `Change` are not blank, then you can mark that grouping as `"Done"` in `Status`

```
Sub Stuff()

    Dim groupPattern As String: groupPattern = Range("B1").Value2

    Dim groupStart As Long: groupStart = 1
    Dim groupEnd As Long: groupEnd = 1

    Dim groupRange As Range

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        If Cells(i, "B").Value2 <> groupPattern Then

            groupEnd = i - 1
            groupPattern = Cells(i, "B").Value2

            Set groupRange = Range("C" & groupStart & ":" & "C" & groupEnd)

            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(groupRange) = groupRange.count Then
                groupRange.offset(0, 1).Value2 = "Done"
            End If

            groupStart = i

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think I couldn't communicate the condition properly to you. It is not that the 'Done' will be filled just based on the value of column B. The condition is if for all instances of a particular value in column B, the value in column C is 'ok', only then can column D be filled with 'Done'. Like in the example I had stated above, column D is not getting filled with 'Done' simply because the value in column A is 'BBB', but it's because for all 'BBB', the corresponding value in column C is 'ok'.

Comment: @DebojitBhowmick maybe giving the column headers would make this easier to talk about

Comment: Apologies, yes it is column B I meant. I initially replied on my question with the column number since that how I framed the question. Here I had switched to letter, since that's how the answer has been replied, hence the confusion.

Comment: Agreed. I will try to edit my original question to include the headers.

Comment: @DebojitBhowmick it happens, sorry i got a little frustrated. I believe I understand the problem now, though, and am reworking the solution

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. When run, it is filling up column D with 'Done' for all rows with 'ok' in column C.

Comment: @DebojitBhowmick whoops! i forgot to reset `groupPattern` for each new grouping